# Inserting a record with null variable does not hit DataAccessException try/catch block

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am calling a save method on an object that has a null field. My table does not allow for this field to be null and I want in case this happens to handle it some other way.

```
        try {
            insert(myRecordHere); //insert has the save() method
        } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
            handleithere();
        }
```

The message I am receiving is

> o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01400: cannot insert
>   NULL into

Why DataAccessException  is not getting called?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the right method to call is not save() but saveAndFlush().